# _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: , error: command '

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i m trying to import mysqldb but i get following error, please help me how i can resolve this 
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: How is this related to python?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? If you are trying to migrate one or more db you should do it with a Mysql Dump and not copying mysql data folder

Comment: I was having the same problem I found this video by chance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SnE0r7g2lE You can do the help, in my case, have responded with the same version of msqlclient. The versions for the use of the pip use the python command and check the system version in my case 32 and the system was asking for a 64. In this link you make unofficial summers: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient but the project is the same. Hope this helps.